# How to add same table row using query?

Tags: jquery, row, new-operator

I'm building a table using jsp. The table contains 9 columns, some of the columns have combo boxes which are built using data from the database. I have to generate the same row when I click on AddNewRow button. In the table the first column is a checkbox that represents the unique id for each row item.

I tried to write code to solve this problem, but I'm not getting the unique id for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var the_row = $('tr#the_row');
the_row.clone().appendAfter(the_row);
```